# Ping IP-adress and loop until a range up to 50 in from another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have one Excel Workbook where column O has a lot of IP-adresses from different subnets eg. 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.1.0 etc.
I would like from another Workbook use those IP-adresses and ping a range of 50 adresses per subnets. 
Ex. 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.50 and 192.168.1.0-192.168.1.50.
The adresses and the status should be written in the new workbook.

I have a good ping code which pings adresses in one column and gives the result in another column.
My issue is that I don´t have all IP-adresses already written down and the list is dynamic and may change.
I also doesn´t manage to paste the status in the new Workbook and I dont know how to change that.

```
Sub GetIPStatus()

  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim ipRng As Range
  Dim Result As String

'Workbook which contains data I want to use in the script
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Wks As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Temp\RetrieveDataFrom.xlsm")
Set Wks = wb.Sheets("Datakom")

'Workbook where I want do write result in
Dim WorkB As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set WorkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Temp\Test.xlsm")
Set Ws = WorkB.Worksheets("Test1")

Set ipRng = Wks.Range("O2")
Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, ipRng.Column).End(xlUp)
Set ipRng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < ipRng.Row, ipRng, Wks.Range(ipRng, RngEnd))

  For Each Cell In ipRng
    Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
    WorkB.Cell.Offset(0, 2) = Result
    If Result = "Connected" Then
        WorkB.Cell.Offset(0, 3) = Now()
    End If
  Next Cell

End Sub
```

I don´t get error I just the the information in the wrong Workbook.
Plus I don´t know how to loop through the range per IP-adress.

Answer (score 1):

In your for each loop, the cells.offset do not have a workbook attached to them, so VBA is putting the values in the active workbook. State the workbook name before the cells.offset, and this should fix your problem.

NOTE: I would open the workbook first, and then set the name of the workbook to a variable, otherwise when you call on the variable set to opening a workbook, it will continue to open that workbook.

For example:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Temp\Test.xlsm")
Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsm")
Set Wks = wb.Sheets("Datakom")
```

.
.
.

```
  For Each Cell In ipRng
    Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
    wb.Cell.Offset(0, 2) = Result
    If Result = "Connected" Then
        wb.Cell.Offset(0, 3) = Now()
    End If
  Next Cell
```

Comment: I changed the For Each loopso it point to the Workbook I wan´t to store the data in.
But It doesn´t gives any errors nor writes anything in the sheet.
My gues is that it is because the WorkB.Cell.Offset(0,2) = Result and WorkB.Cell.Offset(0,3) = Now() doesn´t specify which column since it is another Workbook i´m working in, right?

Comment: Yes, however, I noticed that you set the variable ipRng twice. Is that on purpose? And why?

Comment: Good question (I havn't written the code). But isn´t it because first time ipRng is set it is used to provide correct info for RngEnd and next time it is set for the range when we know the end of the range?

Comment: Why not just create another variable instead of using one you have used before? Try that, I have an inkling that may solve it haha.